# Responsebody is null everytime

Tags: android, flutter, http, mobile, signing

The following code is login control in Flutter. Firstly I entered true user but the response is null, then I entered false login, also the response is null. What's wrong?

```
Future save() async {
        var res = await http.post("http://localhost:8080/signinUser",
            headers: <String, String>{
              'Context-Type': 'application/json;charSet=UTF-8'
            },
            body: <String, String>{
              'email': user.email,
              'password': user.password
            });
        print(res.body);
        if(res.body!=null){
          Navigator.push(
              context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Dashboard()));
        }
    
      }
```

Comment: [`Response.body`](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Response/body.html) is a non-nullable `String`.  It *cannot* be `null`.  Exactly what are you observing that makes you think it's `null`?  What is printed?  Do you instead mean that `res.body` is the empty string?  If so, have you checked `res.statusCode`?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand your situation now.  If you're expecting the response to be a JSON-encoded string, then see [How to properly test response.body is null in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71686316/).