# How to properly test response.body is null in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Flutter API I a getting an error

> flutter: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast

when the response json list is empty. My API is written in Go. `log.Println(mattersJSON)` returns `[1111 2222 3333 4444]` and `fmt.Println(string(mattersJSON))` returns null. This is expected as the query returns no records.

In Flutter, I have this code in my Api:

```
Future<List<Matter>> getMatters(BuildContext context) async {
List<Matter> matters = [];

try {
  final response = await _helper.get(context, "/matters");

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.body);

    if (response.body == null) {
      return [];
    }

    print(response.body.length);

    print('skipped test');
    var parsed = json.decode(response.body) as List<dynamic>;

    for (var matter in parsed) {
      matters.add(Matter.fromJson(matter));
    }
  } else {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, RoutePaths.login);
    return matters;
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
  return matters;
}

return matters;
}
```

The output is this:

> flutter: null
> flutter: 4
> flutter: skipped test
> flutter: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast

I'm tempted to assume that an empty response.body list will always have a length of 4 and that a response.body with records will always have have a length greater than 4. If so, then I could just test for a `response.body.length > 4`. However this is not elegant and probably fragile. I'm concerned that the error I'm seeing says the list is null and `print(response.body)` returns null but the response.body is not null.

How can I properly test for an empty response list and return []?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you're talking about `Response` from `package:http`, then [`Response.body`](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Response/body.html) is non-nullable and cannot be `null`.

It sounds like `response.body` is the literal string `'null'`.  That would be reasonable if you're expecting JSON. **Ultimately your problem is that you are performing an unconditional cast** (`as List<dynamic>`). `json.decode` returns a `dynamic` type and not a `List` or a `Map` precisely because it might return a different types of objects, so the proper fix is to just check first:

```dart
    var parsed = json.decode(response.body);
    if (parsed is List<dynamic>) {
      for (var matter in parsed) {
        matters.add(Matter.fromJson(matter));
      }
    }
```

and then you don't need to explicitly check for `response.body` being the string `'null'` or for `json.decode` returning `null`.