# showing console an error while there is no record in firebase data

Tags: flutter

I am fetching order data from firebase, working all well but if there is no data it showing error in console

I have added a if statement if data not available, even thought its not solving

here is my code for fetching order data and something happening with products list if no product in firebase data

so how to solve now if no product

```
Future<void> fetchandsetorders() async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        myelin);
    final response = await http.get(url);
    final List<OrderItem> loadedorders = [];
    final extradeddata = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    
//I added this statement but still not solving
if(extradeddata==null)
      return;
    extradeddata.forEach((orderid, orderdata) {
      loadedorders.add(
        OrderItem(
          id: orderid,
          products: (orderdata['products'] as List<dynamic>).map((item) {
            return CartItem(
                id: item['id'],
                title: item['title'],
                quantity: item['qty'],
                price: item['price']);
          }).toList(),
          amount: orderdata['amount'],
          date: DateTime.parse(orderdata['date']),
        ),

      );
    });

    _orders=loadedorders;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

showing error is

```
E/flutter (32144): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast
E/flutter (32144): #0      Orders.fetchandsetorders (package:finalshopapp/orders.dart:31:53)
E/flutter (32144): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're facing is caused from this line:

```dart
final extradeddata = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

When `response.body` is null, you can't cast it to `Map<String, dynamic>`

So, one solution could be is to check if `response.body` is null, before casting it to Map. Sample code:

```dart
Future<void> fetchandsetorders() async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        myelin);
    final response = await http.get(url);
    final List<OrderItem> loadedorders = [];
    // Add this line here
    if (response.body == null) return;
    final extradeddata = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    
// NO NEED FOR THIS
//if(extradeddata==null)
      //return;
    extradeddata.forEach((orderid, orderdata) {
      loadedorders.add(
        OrderItem(
          id: orderid,
          products: (orderdata['products'] as List<dynamic>).map((item) {
            return CartItem(
                id: item['id'],
                title: item['title'],
                quantity: item['qty'],
                price: item['price']);
          }).toList(),
          amount: orderdata['amount'],
          date: DateTime.parse(orderdata['date']),
        ),

      );
    });

    _orders=loadedorders;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: I have tried this one too but not working that's why I am much confused...failing find problem

Comment: Are you getting the same error?

Comment: Yes same error after editing with your code

Comment: wait, it is jsonDecode and not json.decode, and you have to import dart:convert

Comment: @IrfanGanatra can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71686526/12391548 ?

Comment: Thanks...It worked....but one more challenge I got is to understand null....actually print(response.body) was giving null in output but can't compare in if...so this is what. have to study further for null

Comment: All errors gone.....Thanks

Comment: I have already done it

Comment: New problems generated...now it not showing even though I have records...can u send code , it stops spider if no record but the same with if records are there...showing no records